# How to use javascript method in Vue template

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to split the last end of the URL to get numeric value. It is throwing an error. I haven't used vue in a while but I know we can use methods/function to get desired results? Where am I doing it wrong?

```
<ul>
    <li  v-for="(character, index) in characters" :key="index">
     <router-link :to="'/characters'+ character.url.split("/").pop()">
        {{character.name}}
      </router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: *It is throwing an error* - what's the error? but, can you see the issue? you've got the string `"'/characters'+ character.url.split("` then `/` then `").pop()"` ... so, you're dividing `"'/characters'+ character.url.split("` by `").pop()"` ?

Comment: @Bravo what u mean? i.e. ```https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1``` and I want to get the numeric value after last ```/``` if that makes sense?

Comment: Did you use single quotes in split ?

Comment: @dnaz the error went away but the code isnt outputting anything.

Comment: @Nofel - look at the string ... you try to put `"` within `"` - that's not how javascript works ...`var x = "This is "a" string"` does not result in x being the string `This is "a" string` - it results in a syntax error and unparsed javascript .... you still haven't told us the error that is being thrown ... surely it's more than just "an error"

Comment: That's a lot of code in the template; it would be better to refactor it into a method.

Comment: Check the "character.url" , is it right format ? Maybe this ends with slash, so that you get empty result. Check the string format that you split up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, hope this helps:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    character: {
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/101'
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-html="`/characters/${character.url.split('/').pop()}`"></div>
  <div> {{ `/characters/${character.url.split('/').pop()}` }}</div>
</div>
```

I am using string literals (Template literals or Template strings) to keep the code clean by eliminating some double/single quotes and `+` used for concatenation.

Comment: he could also use a computed value depending on the use case, or a method that would do this for him.

Comment: @Jhecht he can use `computed` if he is using custom component otherwise he cannot use `computed` because he is in `v-for` loop and `computed` doesn't accept arguments like `methods` do.